# How to run one method at a time in java?

Tags: java, methods, thread-sleep

Just say I have 4 methods from two different classes.. class1.method1(), class1.method2(), class2.method3(),class2.method4().

method1 will be streaming data to a database which can take a few minutes to execute.
method2 will use the data in the database to generate a text file.

How can I program the start point of the program to run method1() first when it has completed run method2() and so on.

I have looked into threads which I just seem to be looking at timing sleep methods. Anyone have a solution to this? if i run the code as it is then it results in method2 being executed while data is STILL being streamed into database so I need it to wait until method1 has stopped.

```
//start point for program
  public static void main(String[]args){
  //run first until all data is inputted into database
  class1.method1();
 //then run next method until completed
 class1.method2();
 //so on..
```

Comment: That's what it does by default. You don't need threads. Your sample code already does what you want.

Comment: Java runs methods sequentially unless you tell it otherwise. So don't worry, it will run methods in the order you call them

Comment: But that's how Java works by default. Did I miss something?

Comment: just to add, method 1 is streaming data to a database, method 2 is using this data to create a txt file. When run the methods in order I get a blank text file however if I just run method1 until it finishes then run method2 it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple.

Java code runs *statement by statement*, unless you tell it otherwise using threads &c.

(Formally the Java interpreter is allowed to *reorder* statements as an optimisation strategy but only if there are *no* side effects).

Comment: hey, Method1 is streaming data into a database,  where as method 2() and method()3 needs to access the database data to write text files. However when I run it statement by statement it leads to empty txt files!

Comment: Did you *close* the stream between the write and read?

Comment: yup its all closed. If i run the methods individually it works grand. But I was looking to run all the methods at once thinking java would wait until the stream to the database closed before going onto the next method.

Comment: Nope. I/O is normally *buffered*.

Answer (score 1):

maybe I don't understand the question, java acting like you need.
As you write, first is executed method1, when is totally completed is executed method2 an so on.

Answer (score 0):

By default methods are blocked aslong as they dont run in a different Thread. If you want to have Threaded method calls (which i guess that you are looking for) then you need to sync them. Else Java will run statement by statement.

Answer (score 0):

It already does what you want it to do.
Here:

```
 public static void main(String[]args){

 class1.method1(); // this will run first until it totally gets completed

 class1.method2(); // Now this method will run
}
```

As in java everything gets executed statement by statement and thats what your code is doing.

Comment: hey, Method1 is streaming data into a database, where as method 2() and method()3 needs to access the database data to write text files. However when I run it statement by statement it leads to empty txt files!

Comment: Can you be more specific? or try editing your code with some more information. I'm assuming you are talking about files here, so you need to flush() and close() your streams.

Comment: I updated my question now. I hope this is better to understand

Comment: Well as i said earlier `in java everything gets executed statement by statement` and that is what your code is doing thought you can try `synchronized` keyword .                                                                                           `Synchronized methods enable a simple strategy for preventing thread interference and memory consistency errors: if an object is visible to more than one thread, all reads or writes to that object's variables are done through synchronized methods.`